# GRETL Scripting: Is it possible to user OPEN with a string variable without $workdir?

Tags: scripting, gretl

So I'm doing a GRETL script where the users writes his Operating System (Windows/Linux), his path to a gretl workdir and the .gdt file to open (saved from a previous exercise).

This passes on string variables. One of such variables is `gdt_file` which before opening should be `/path/to/file/file.gdt`

Now, reading GRETL documentation, the `open` command will by default look for `file.gdt` inside the `$workdir`.

Now, what I want to do is `open gdt_file`, but of course it doesn't work because it's looking for `gdt_file.gdt` inside `$workdir`, instead of `open /path/to/file/file.gdt`

I've played a bit with it, but I'm unable to find a workaround, IDK if this is even possible, the documentation isn't very clarifying.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

here's the thread with the reply from the Gretl team, in case anyone is wondering: https://sourceforge.net/p/gretl/bugs/247/

Basically, use command "@variable" as in string substitution in the gretl guide.